# Is building a BST with N given elements is O(n lg n)?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

What would be the worst case time complexity to build binary search tree with given arbitrary N elements ?

I think there is a difference between **N given elements** and the **elements coming one by one and thereby making a BST of total N elements** .

In the former case, it is **O(n log n)** and in second one is **O(n^2)** . Am i right ?

Comment: What's different about taking elements one by one, and then deal with the whole thing at once?

Comment: I think , the later case can build a Skewed BST , thereby having O(n^2)

Comment: Accepting numbers one by one is O(n) in time and O(n) in space. You can now sort them, and build a perfect tree in O(n*log n). If you must build tree as you go (i.e. no additional O(n) space for the input is available) then you may end up with an unbalanced tree for O(n^2) worst case.

Comment: yes, this is more clear to me . Its all about space right . If i am not having space to hold integers , then it gives a skewed , otherwise , i can collect and store them all to sort and get balanced tree , right?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: But can't you use a self-balancing tree structure to reduce the O(n^2) time to O(n log n)?

Comment: Yes, we can use , but what if it is not .. Just the BST  not AVL

Comment: If it's just BST, then worst case or inserting one item at a time is O(n^2). If you inserted the numbers 1 through N, one at a time, in order, you'd end up with a degenerate tree of depth N.

Answer (score 2):

If [Binary Search Tree (BST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) is not perfectly balanced, then the worst case time complexity is `O(n^2)`. Generally, BST is build by repeated insertion, so worst case will be `O(n^2)`. But if you can sort the input (in `O(nlogn)`), it can be built in `O(n)`, resulting in overall complexity of `O(nlogn)`

It BST is [self-balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), then the worst case time complexity is `O(nlog n)` even if we have repeated insertion.

Comment: (Actually, ***perfectly** balanced* (depth of leaves differs by at most one) isn't a prerequisite. *Any* limit on depth appears as one of the factors in the function limiting run time.)

Comment: If you rebalance the tree as you build it (and some ways like treaps require no extra data in the nodes), then you can build the tree one node at a time in O(n log n) time.